# I would like to add numerical limits to this block of code

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

```
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    var charValue = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    if (((!/^(\d+)?([.]?\d{0,1})?$/.test(this.value + e.key)) && (e.which != 8))) {
      e.preventDefault()
    }
  })
})

SetPoint :<input id="input" type="text" name="setPoint"   max="5" min="1" />
```

this block of code is a bit beyond my understanding but I'm guessing you use e.something and <= in the if statement to add a less than or equal to limit the number that the form will accept

Comment: What have you tried and what seems to go wrong?

Comment: "this block of code is a bit beyond my understanding": This is your first problem. Start by commenting every line and making sure that you understand what it does and why it's there. Once you understand the code, you will be able to solve your problem without guessing.

Comment: @Done Rine Am I right guessing it is e.something though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime you type a letter in the keyboard, you got a specific `e.keyCode` or `e.key`. Try to debug the value of each variable to understand the code.

To put a limit simply do a check to prevent default behavior (prevent further typing)

```
var nextValue = this.value + e.key;
if (nextValue < 1 || nextValue > 5) {
    e.preventDefault()
}
```